# How to add vertical spacing between Bootstrap Cards

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am working with boostrap cards, and the following is what I have them currently looking like:
[image]

Now what I'd like to do is add vertical space between the cards so that Card 1 and Card 3 aren't stuck together as well as Card 2 and Card 4.

The following is my code and setup for the cards I currently have:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">CARD 1</h5>
          <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">CARD 2</h5>
          <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">CARD 3</h5>
          <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">CARD 4</h5>
          <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: which version of BS you are using?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add Class `mb-3` for `<div class="col-sm-6 mb-3">`

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">CARD 1</h5>
          <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">CARD 2</h5>
          <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">CARD 3</h5>
          <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">CARD 4</h5>
          <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

if you want more space, bootstrap class available like `mb-4` `mb-5`

more info  [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/)

Answer (score 2):

Add `margin-bottom: 20px` inside a `card` class in `css` file. check the below simple css.

In style.css file

```
.card { 
    margin-bottom: 20px !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add something like this (SCSS):

```
div[class^="col-"] {
   padding-top: 1rem;
   padding-bottom: 1rem;

   > h1,
   > h2,
   > h3,
   > h4,
   > h5,
   > h6 {
      margin-top: 0;
   }
}

* + * {
   :last-child {
       margin-bottom: 0;
   }
}
```

... to handle vertical spaces in general.